# std::nothrow doesnt work as expected - Condition is always false

Tags: c++, std, clion

```
#include <iostream>


int main() {


    int *xx = new (std::nothrow) int[2];

    if(xx == NULL)
    {
        exit(1);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Im trying to use `nothrow`, but clion says about `xx == NULL` that "Condition is always false", and about `exit(1)` that  "Unreachable code". What am i doint wrong?

Comment: That sounds like a problem with your IDE.

Comment: You forgot to `#include <new>`.

Comment: @KerrekSB doens't work

Comment: Clearly their code analysis feature is broken and doesn't know about `std::nothrow`. The only thing worse than no code analysis is a shitty one.

Comment: It's also possible that the code analysis can see the implementation of the nothrowing allocation function and figured out that *your particular implementation* always returns a non-null value. That's unfortunate.

Comment: The snippets is correct. Check your IDE, this should be the problem. By the way, as said by @Kerrek SB #include <new>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a bug in CLion - [CPP-989](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-989)